# Dash does not show applications available for installation

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

When I go to applications lens (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), I can search for available applications and install them. From the general (home?) lens, I can list only application that are actually installed, not those that are available.

I vaguely remember application used to show up in the home lense and maybe I disabled it but I am not sure. Or maybe this is the correct behaviour and my memory fails me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour! May be you browsed the lens using the buttons given on the bottom and then clicked on Applications lens(the second one from left) and then asked some application to be installed(?).

Comment: Hm, weird. I swear those application available to install were there, once. But as long as it is intended, I can live with that. Thanks for the answer